# Having an issue with inherited class declaration

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files

So I am trying to run a test project to see how a class B inherits from a class A. However, when I tried to compile the project, I got a "expected class-name before {" token. Could anyone point out the flaw in my class interface and implementations? Thanks.

```
//in a.h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

  class a{
      public:
         a();
  };

//in b.h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

  class b: public a{ //error occurs at this line
      public:
         b();

  };
```

Thanks for any feedbacks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to

```
#include "a.h"
```

in b.h.